# Display Table in Full (Not Cut by the end of page)

Tags: tables

I created a table by using the following code in overleaf with TeX Live version 2022.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[commentColor=black, indLines=false]{algpseudocodex}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\captionof{table}{Transitions and Places of TEG in Fig.\ref{fig:TEG_5_Steps}}
\label{tab:table_TEG} 
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth} { |
  l |
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X |
  c |
}
  \hline
  \textbf{Place/Transition} & \textbf{Explanation} & \textbf{Time}  \\
  \hline
  $T_1$ and $T_{2(n+1)}$  & Robot operation which relates to loadlocks. Transition $T_1$ indicates that wafer unloading from the loadlocks and $T_{2(n+1)}$ means that the robot loads the wafer to the loadlocks. & $w$ \\
  \hline
  $T_2,T_3,\ldots,T_{2n}, T_{2n+1}$ & Robot performs unloading or loading operation between the steps. & $w$ \\
  \hline
  $P_k^R$ & Place which indicates the robot movement from a chamber to another one or from the loadlocks to the chambers or vice versa. & $v$
  \\
  \hline
  $P_i^{\prime}$ & The processing or cleaning places which receive the tokens from the clockwise arcs. & $p_i$ or $c_i$
  \\
  \hline
  $P_i^{\prime\prime}$  & The processing or cleaning places which receive the tokens from the counterclockwise arcs. & $p_i$ or $c_i$
  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

However the table was cut at the end of page as shown in the following screenshot.
[image: result]

Having said this, does anyone know what code should I add in order to make sure the table could be displayed in full?

Thank you.

Comment: Please use `table` float.

Comment: A table is limited to one page it cannot go onto a second page. Your table is too long.